# Get the first date and last date of the current quarter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to write a query which will show me the first date and last date of the current quarter.

It would be similar to the below:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'), 0), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS output_from_date
FROM dual;
```

Comment: No, it won't be similar. The first and last date of the quarter are both **dates**, just like `sysdate`. The query you showed us will return a string, not a date. You should not convert to string unless this is just for a final report; if you need to use the dates, for example, to select only rows with dates in this quarter, you should definitely **not** convert to strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the last date, by getting first day of next quarter (plus 3 month) minus 1:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q') AS first_quarter_date, 
ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'), 3) -1 AS last_quarter_date
from dual;
```